# Disappearing term while integrating substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck this example found in *Essential Calculus: Early Transcendentals* by James Stewart, Chapter 6.4:

The difficulty is in the first integral:

$$\int u\sqrt{u^2+3}\;du \;- \int\sqrt{u^2+3}\;du$$

> The first integral is evaluated using the substitution 
>   $t = u^2 + 3$:

$$\int u\sqrt{u^2+3}\;du  = \frac 12\int\sqrt{t}\;dt = \frac 12 * \frac 23t^{\frac32} = \frac13(u^2 + 3)^{\frac32}$$

The chapter is on using tables of integrals, so we want the integral to fit into a form to which we have convenient access.
However, there is no explanation as to why $\int u\sqrt{u^2+3}\;du  = \frac 12\int\sqrt{t}\;dt$. **How does that work?**

My understanding says that when you integrate the $u$ with respect to $u$, $t$ can be considered a constant and you might end up with something like:

$$\int u\sqrt{u^2 + 3}\;du = \int u\sqrt{t}\;du = \sqrt{t}\int u\;du = \frac12{u^2}\sqrt{t}$$

Doing that provides the familiar coefficient of one half and square root of $t$, but you have used up the integral and differential and instead get more of the $u$ term.

Or, knowing
$$u = \sqrt{t-3} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;du =\frac23(t-3)^{\frac32}dt$$

You could say 
$$u\int\sqrt{t}\;du = \frac23\int(t-3)^2\sqrt{t}\;dt$$

Which becomes its own abysmal mess that shows little hint of promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**how does that work?**"

We have
$$
\int u\sqrt{u^2 + 3} du.
$$

Now let $t = u^2 +3$ then $dt = 2u\cdot du$ thus $du = \frac{dt}{2u}$ which yields

$$
\int u\sqrt{u^2 + 3} du = \int u \cdot \sqrt{t} \frac{dt}{2u} = \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{t} dt.
$$

Comment: My goodness, how obvious it is when someone else points it out. Thank you.

Comment: Well, from experience, it happends more often then one wishes. @Naltroc :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a substitution such as the one in the OP, there are two steps:

1. First, pick a definition of a new dummy variable in terms of the original dummy variable.  This is where the skill/experience comes in.  Choosing this substitution function is the critical step in simplifying the problem.

In this case, the substitution is:$$t=u^2+3$$

2. The next step is to use this substitution to eliminate ***all*** instances of the original dummy variable, ***including the differential***.  In the process, the integral will become simpler, if Step #1 has been carried out successfully.

In this case, it's obvious that the expression under the root sign is replaced by just $t$.

It would be tempting to then rearrange the substitution to get an expression (a messy one) in $t$ to replace the term $u$ in the original integral.

However, if you take a look at the differential, $du$ and find the corresponding differential for $dt$, we get:$$dt=2udu$$

And now we see why the original substitution was chosen:  the portion $u du$ can be replaced with $dt/2$, and the integral ***is*** simplified.